# How to build LineageOs for the hero2lte device?

Tags: android-source, lineageos

The method to build lineageos from source used to be very straight forward but I'm not having success when building it to the device hero2lte which is the Samsung galaxy S7 Edge.

To reproduce the issue, just follow the build steps according to [official documentation](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/hero2lte/build), the only difference is that I'm trying to build lineage-15.1 branch instead.

`repo init -u https://github.com/LineageOS/android.git -b lineage-15.1`

And I also tried adding manually the repos for the device, kernel and vendor trees in `local_manifests.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>

    <remote name="vendor"

            fetch="https://github.com"

            revision="lineage-15.1" />



    <remote name="device"

            fetch="https://github.com"

            revision="lineage-15.1"/>



    <remote name="kernel"

            fetch="https://github.com"

            revision="lineage-15.1"/>

  <project name="TheMuppets/proprietary_vendor_samsung" path="vendor/samsung" remote="vendor"/>
  <project name="LineageOS/android_device_samsung_hero2lte" path="device/samsung/hero2lte" remote="device" />
  <project name="LineageOS/android_hardware_samsung" path="hardware/samsung" remote="github" />
  <project name="LineageOS/android_kernel_samsung_universal8890" path="kernel/samsung/universal8890" remote="kernel" />
</manifest>
```

But every way I try ends up in the error when I run `breakfast hero2lte`:

> including vendor/lineage/vendorsetup.sh
>   build/core/product_config.mk:243: ***
>
>   _nic.PRODUCTS.[[device/samsung/hero2lte/lineage.mk]]: "device/samsung/hero-common/hero-common.mk" does not exist.  Stop.
>
>   Device hero2lte not found. Attempting to retrieve device repository
>
>   from LineageOS Github (http://github.com/LineageOS). Found repository:
>
>   android_device_samsung_hero2lte Default revision: lineage-15.1
>
>   Checking branch info Checking if device/samsung/hero2lte is fetched
>
>   from android_device_samsung_hero2lte
>
>   LineageOS/android_device_samsung_hero2lte already fetched to
>
>   device/samsung/hero2lte Syncing repository to retrieve project.
>
>   remote: Enumerating objects: 13, done.         remote: Counting
>
>   objects: 100% (13/13), done.         remote: Compressing objects: 100%
>
>   (11/11), done.         remote: Total 17 (delta 4), reused 7 (delta 1),
>
>   pack-reused 4         From git://github.com/LineageOS/android   
>
>   f56ece1..800af59  lineage-16.0 -> origin/lineage-16.0   
>
>   43f3fd0..152210f  lineage-17.0 -> origin/lineage-17.0 fatal: duplicate
>
>   path device/samsung/hero2lte in
>
>   /home/fabio/android/lineage15.1/.repo/manifest.xml Repository synced!
>
>   Looking for dependencies in device/samsung/hero2lte Looking for
>
>   dependencies in device/samsung/hero-common device/samsung/hero-common
>
>   has no additional dependencies. Done build/core/product_config.mk:243:
>
>   *** _nic.PRODUCTS.[[device/samsung/hero2lte/lineage.mk]]: "device/samsung/hero-common/hero-common.mk" does not exist.  Stop.
>   
>   build/core/product_config.mk:243: ***
>   _nic.PRODUCTS.[[device/samsung/hero2lte/lineage.mk]]: "device/samsung/hero-common/hero-common.mk" does not exist.  Stop.
>   
>   ** Don't have a product spec for: 'lineage_hero2lte'
>   ** Do you have the right repo manifest?

**EDIT**  In my example I'm building for `lineage-15.1` but I'm accepting answers for `lineage-16.0` or `lineage-17.1` too. Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's probably not the source of the problem, but `fatal: duplicate
path device/samsung/hero2lte in
/home/fabio/android/lineage15.1/.repo/manifest.xml` looks suspiciously, I recommend checking what causes that, may be something else is wrong too

Comment: also you may try to use https://github.com/ivanmeler/local_manifests/blob/heroXlte-lineage-15.1/roomservice.xml - AFAIK Ivan Meler is the author of hero2lte LineageOS port https://forum.xda-developers.com/s7-edge/development/lineageos-15-android-8-0-0-s7-edge-t3710101

Comment: @Mixaz I've tried adding his repos but I am still having the same error

Comment: sorry, I don't know what's going on in your log. You can try to ask this question in #lineageos-dev IRC channel at freenode, may be somebody faced that issues. Post link to this question there.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on [android.se]. It's not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `local_manifest.xml` is missing the [hero-common](https://github.com/LineageOS/android_device_samsung_hero-common) repo.

```xml
<project name="LineageOS/android_device_samsung_hero-common" path="device/samsung/hero-common" remote="device" />
```

Comment: No, I have this repo in another manifest bcz when I added to the local it failed with error message saying that it's duplicated

Comment: Does `device/samsung/hero-common/hero-common.mk` exist in your AOSP?